# Querying Dataset to get Distance using Latitude/Longitude Function

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Good morning,

I am working on a project for work and am at a bit of an impasse. What I am trying to do is take a list of records (the records house the zipcode, latitude, and longitude of a store) and place them into the closest market.

I have a function that will compare 2 zipcodes and their related latitude and longitude and get the distance. The function works just fine when inputting the records in 1 at a time.

What I am trying to do is figure out a way to have the function work through the given records 1 at a time and give me the distance.

What I currently have is:

declare @i int
select @i = min(RowID) from #unmatched2
declare @max int
select @max = max(RowID) from #unmatched2 while @i <= @max 
begin
select Zipcode, Longitude, Latitude from #unmatched2 where RowID = @i

```
DECLARE @Lat1 float
DECLARE @Long1 float
DECLARE @Lat2 float
DECLARE @Long2 float

SELECT  @Lat1 = max(Latitude) from #unmatched2 
where   RowID = @i
SELECT  @Long1 = max(Longitude) from #unmatched2 
where   RowID = @i
SELECT  @Lat2 = max(Latitude) from ProgramManagement.dbo.zipcode_lookup 
where   ZIPCode = 92101
SELECT  @Long2 = max(Longitude) from ProgramManagement.dbo.zipcode_lookup 
where   ZIPCode = 92101
select ProgramManagement.dbo.CoordinateDistanceMiles(@Lat1, @Long1, @Lat2, @Long2)
set @i = @i + 1  end
```

@database is my temp table I am using to get the rowcount. for instance in this case I am using #unmatched.

A sample record is:

```
 Zipcode, latitude , longitude 
 92101 , 32.7152778, -117.1563889
```

The output would simply be a single number in distance:

```
140.01
```

So the temp table would have ~1300 records and the output would be a single number for each row.

Currently the above is working and it is going through the entire table but my output comes out in seperate results. The 1st is:

```
Zipcode Longitude   Latitude
93510   -118.1824020000 34.4679410000
```

The 2nd is:

```
Distance
134.035921098023
```

What I need to happen is just a list of the results 1 through the end instead of what I am currently getting. Any suggestions? Or is there a way for the results to be:

```
Zipcode     Longitude       Latitude        Distance
93510       118.1824020000  34.4679410000   134.035921..
```

Comment: What is `@databases`? Does it contain the longitudes and latitudes? Could you please post some sample data and expected output of the query?

Comment: @database is my temp table I am using to get the rowcount. for instance in this case I am using #unmatched.

A sample record is:
    Zipcode, latitude,   longitude
    92101  , 32.7152778, -117.1563889

The output would simply be a single number in distance:
    140.01

So the temp table would have ~1300 records and the output would be a single number for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just trying to find the distance from each record in your `#unmatched2` table to a single record in the `zipcode_lookup` table.  The set logic for this is a simple join, then just perform the distance calculation in the select.

```
SELECT u.RowID, u.Zipcode, u.Longitude, u.latitude,
    ProgramManagement.dbo.CoordinateDistanceMiles(u.Latitude, u.Longitude, z.Lat, z.Long) dist
FROM #unmatched2 u
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT max(Latitude) Lat, max(Longitude) Long
    FROM ProgramManagement.dbo.zipcode_lookup
    WHERE ZIPCode = 92101
  ) z
```

This is assuming that RowID is a unique identifier, if not, simple group on it... (this is actually closer to what your loop does)

```
SELECT u.RowID, u.Zipcode,
    max(u.Longitude) Longitude, max(u.latitude) Latitude,
    ProgramManagement.dbo.CoordinateDistanceMiles(max(u.Latitude), max(u.Longitude), z.Lat, z.Long) dist
FROM #unmatched2 u
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT max(Latitude) Lat, max(Longitude) Long
    FROM ProgramManagement.dbo.zipcode_lookup
    WHERE ZIPCode = 92101
  ) z
GROUP BY u.RowID, u.Zipcode
```